# Can't have Nuget.config in source control?

Tags: tfs, nuget, visual-studio-2015

In one of our projects, I've recently converted from the (now broken) old-school MSBuild based automatic package restore to the shiny new automatic package restore in Nuget 3.0 (Visual Studio 2015 RTM default).

As the official guidance suggests, I have created a `.nuget/Nuget.config` file in the solution folder to stop it from uploading the binaries. No more clutter in source control. Life is good.

However, this doesn't work on other machines if the `Nuget.config` isn't itself included in source control, so I have done just that. Now life is bad again.

Visual Studio can't load Nuget correctly and the error log indicates that it can't open `.nuget/Nuget.config` read-write. Which is fair enough, since it's under TFS source control and not checked out.

So here's the question: How to have my cake and eat it, too?

Comment: Also, stop using server workspaces and you won't have problems with files not being able to be modified if they're not checked out first. Server workspaces are archaic.

Comment: Unfortunately, local workspaces quickly become a conflict nightmare. Especially with bigger refactorings (renaming namespaces, moving interfaces to their own project, etc.). With server workspaces, you don't have to care. It either works or it doesn't, but you mostly don't have to care about conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to Nuget 3.1.1, it behaves as expected and doesn't open the file read-write.
Delicious cake.

*The discussion for this (closed) issue is here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1103.*